# can not connect to gcloud using ssh?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Using the promotionals credits (the 300$ opening account promotion), i used to connect my VM using SSH `gcloud compute ssh instance_name` all was fine.

End of promotional credits, i linked the project to my billing account. Then now, running the same SSH connection return this error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) Error while connecting [4033: 'not authorized'].
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

I don t get it... the VPC is fine, the firewall got all ports open.

Do i really have to set an iap tunnel ? Why the normal SSH connection is not working anymore ?

Thanks if someone can confirm (before i change what was working well).

Comment: Have you upgraded billing before the trial period ended?

Comment: No, my ssh access has been block because the trial period was over, then i upgraded the billing, which unlocked the ssh access but now end on that Error. From this post i setted up the IAP tunnel but it didin't solved anything, the same Error remain.

Comment: Please try to create another VM and check how it works for testing purposes.

Comment: Finally that what i did, i killed the original project and rebuilt it (using exactly the same configuration). All is back to normal, i can connect the VM using ssh. Do you have an idea where does the problem come from (i am curious about it) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accordingly to your comment the Free Trial was ended, I assume that your issue is related to the deletion process started when the Free Trial ends. Please have a look at the documentation [End of the Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end) to find more details:

> The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days,
> whichever happens first. At that time, the following conditions apply:
>
> - To continue using Google Cloud, you must [upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).
> - **All resources you created during the trial are stopped**.
> - **Any data you stored in Compute Engine is marked for deletion and might be lost**. - [Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline).
> - Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google
>   Cloud services during the trial period.
> - You might receive a message stating that your Cloud Billing account has been canceled, which indicates that your account has been
>   suspended to prevent charges.